# Passing information from universal link into view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've set up a successful Universal Link, which when opened pushes the user to a 'callback' screen. This Universal Link is called after a successful connection to a third party API. When successful, this this API returns a 'code' which I need to do a bunch of stuff in my app's backend.

At the moment, I can log this code successfully in my scene delegate with the following code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        // the url is going to be in userActivity.webpageURL
        
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
                let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
                let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
                return
            }

            // Check for specific URL components that you need.
            guard let params = components.queryItems else {
                return
            }

            if let code = params.first(where: { $0.name == "code" } )?.value {

                print("code = \(code)")
                if (userActivity.webpageURL?.lastPathComponent == "callback") {
                guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

                        print(code)
                        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                        //self.window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        guard let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CallbackViewController") as? CallbackViewController else {
                            print("ViewController not found")
                            return
                        }
                        let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
                        self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

            } else {
                print("Code is missing")
                return
            }
        
    }
```

This code is accessed as the incoming URLs queryItems, and can be logged successfully.

The next step I need to take is accessing this code inside of my view controller. To do this, I have attempted to access the scene delegate like so inside of viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        if let sceneDelegate = self.view.window?.windowScene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
          let variableToAccess = sceneDelegate.code
          print(variableToAccess)
        }
    }
```

However, code apparently doesn't exist. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of try to reach back to your scene delegate from the `CallbackViewController`, you can set it at the time that you instantiate the `CallbackViewController`.

Assuming `CallbackViewController` looks something like this:

```
class CallbackViewController : UIViewController {
  var code : String?
}
```

And then when you instantiate it:

```
guard let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CallbackViewController") as? CallbackViewController else {
   print("ViewController not found")
   return
}
rootVC.code = code
```